# merge 2 DataFrames , keeping the data in the joined column

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

How can I add zero rows to dataframe, by merging index with an array ?

### df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[20170302, 25,0,42], 
                          [20170120, 0,89,1]], 
                       columns=['date','d1','d2','d3'])
       date  d1  d2  d3
0  20170302  25   0  42
1  20170120   0  89   1
```

### date array

```
dates = [20170302, 20170225, 20170120]
```

### Expected output

```
       date  d1  d2  d3
0  20170302  25   0  42
1  20170225   0   0   0
2  20170120   0  89   1
```

I tried to create dates dataframe, and merge. but nosucess

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in ['date']]
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(0, dates, columns=cols)
new = pd.merge(df_dates, df,how='left', left_index=True, right_on='date')
print df_dates
          d1  d2  d3
20170302   0   0   0
20170225   0   0   0
20170120   0   0   0
```

But i got:

```
    d1_x    d2_x    d3_x    date    d1_y    d2_y    d3_y
0   0   0   0   20170302    25.0    0.0 42.0
1   0   0   0   20170225    NaN NaN NaN
1   0   0   0   20170120    0.0 89.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `set_index/reindex/reset_index` to add missing dates:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[20170302, 25,0,42], 
                          [20170120, 0,89,1]], 
                       columns=['date','d1','d2','d3'])
dates = [20170302, 20170225, 20170120]
result = df.set_index('date').reindex(dates, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(result)
```

yields

```
       date  d1  d2  d3
0  20170302  25   0  42
1  20170225   0   0   0
2  20170120   0  89   1
```

Or, you could use `pd.merge` and use `fillna` to replace NaNs with zeros:

```
In [168]: pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame({'date':dates}), how='outer').fillna(0)
Out[168]: 
       date    d1    d2    d3
0  20170302  25.0   0.0  42.0
1  20170120   0.0  89.0   1.0
2  20170225   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Note that `pd.merge` merges on all shared columns by default. So the above call merges on `date`. `how='outer'` causes `pd.merge` to add rows to the result for every date found in either `df` or `pd.DataFrame({'date':dates})`.